# Programs keeps asking for iCloud password when I log in

Tags: icloud, login-items

Whenever I log in a window appears, looks like an Apple program from the icon style displayed in the window, and asks for my iCloud password.

I don't remember installing the program, ever using it, or adding it to my login items. I can in fact not see any to me unknown program in my login items.

What is it?

[image]

(I made my iCloud user name invisible to the casual observer.)

Comment: The icon is for Messages, which comes with OS X. Look at your Dock and I'm willing to bet it's there and set to run at login.

Comment: No, there was nothing in the Dock and it wasn't set to run at login.