# iCloud keeps asking me my password

Tags: icloud, macos, password

I enabled 2fa for my apple account, and now iCloud keeps asking me my password a lot of times every time I login. I think it doesn't even bother to check it, since as soon as I enter it, it pops the window again immediatly after I hit either login or cancel (it gives up after a few tries).

I've created an application-specific password and I'm using that one, to no avail.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125264/programs-keeps-asking-for-icloud-password-when-i-log-in), obviously I can't know if the underlying problem is the same one.

Comment: Not the same, the previous was for Messages on a prior version of OS X.